# An autonomous system that is asymptotically stable is not also exponentially stable.

Tags: dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to find a counter example to the following statement:

> An autonomous system $\dot{x}(t)=f(x)$, that is asymptotically stable is also exponentially stable.

The opposite is true an autonomous system $\dot{x}(t)=f(x)$, that is asymptotically stable is also exponentially stable. But I am having a hard time finding a specific counter example to the original statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Notes** (or things I know already)

- [The definitions of asymptotic stability and exponentially stability I am using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability).
- If I have a Lyapunov function $V(x)$ for $\dot{x}(t)=f(x)$, $\dot{V}(x)<0$ implies asymptotic stability and $\dot{V}(x)\leq aV(x)$ (where $a$ is a constant) exponential stability.
- The statement a non-autonomous system $\dot{x}(t)=f(x,t)$, that is asymptotically stable is also exponentially stable is false.

Comment: [Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2971767/how-to-pick-a-lyapunov-function-and-prove-stability?rq=1)

Comment: $$\dot{x_1}=-x_1^3+\alpha(t)x_2$$
$$\dot{x_2}=-\alpha(t)x_1-x_2^3$$

with $\alpha(t)$ continuous and bounded works with

$$V(x) =\frac{1}{2}\left(x_1^2+x_2^2\right)$$

but I don't think is autonomous.

Comment: The system is under the label of systems with time dependent parameters (which most consider to be a different family of differential equations). I have papers answering my questions in that regard. Also for clarification I am not asking how to find lyapunov functions or prove stability using Lyapunov functions. Unless there is some lyapunov technique to show a system is only asymptotically stable and cannot be exponentially stable. My understanding is that showing a system is asymptotically stable does not disprove it being exponentially stable.

Comment: It is simple to give (simple) counterexamples, do let us know what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try to find a one-dimensional example, to keep things as simple as possible.

You know that $\dot x=-x$ is exponentially stable, and you would like to find a system where the phase portrait looks the same,
$$\longrightarrow 0 \longleftarrow,$$
but where the solutions don't tend to zero so fast. So try making the right-hand side smaller for small $|x|$ while still keeping its sign. For example, this might work:
$$
\dot x = - x^3
.
$$
And indeed it does; if you solve this system (by separation of variables), you'll find that the solutions tend to zero roughly like $1/\sqrt{t}$ as $t \to \infty$, not exponentially.

Comment: That you this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry I have an additional question. If we have the Lyapunov function $V(x)=x^2$ the derivative the $\dot{V}=-2x^4=-2 (V(x))^2$ does this imply exponential stability?

Comment: @AzJ: No, clearly not, as this example shows.